Multirow subplots with numpy arrays, AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'hist'
I've been attempting to create a 2-by-2 grid of plots using matplotlib. My data are numpy arrays, and I am trying to create histograms of the data. However, when I format subplots to output two rows, and two columns of plots, I receive a "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'hist'" error.
Weirdly enough, when I set the plots to be in a 1-by-4 grid, it works perfectly.

My code is as follows:
# plotting distributions of Xbar_n

m = 1000000 # number of samples
n1, n2, n3, n4 = 1,5,25,100 # number of variables
variables = [n1, n2, n3, n4]

def xbar(n, m): # (num variables, num samples)
    dist = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(m,n)).mean(axis=1) # syntax: m is number of samples, i is number of variables
    return dist; # returns m samples of Xbar_n for n number of variables

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(9, 4.5), sharey=True, sharex=True)

for i in range(0,4):
    count, bins, ignored = axs[i].hist(xbar(variables[i],m), 1500, density=True, color="#3c989b")
    axs[i].set_title('$n = {}$'.format(variables[i]), fontsize=16)
    axs[i].minorticks_off()
axs[0].set_ylabel('$f_{\overline{X}_n}$', fontsize=16)

# big axes for common label
fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
# hide tick and tick label of the big axes
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.grid(False)
plt.minorticks_off()
plt.xlabel('$\overline{X}_n$', fontsize=16)
plt.show()

I wish to have
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(9, 4.5), sharey=True, sharex=True)
but doing so outputs the error
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'hist'

With fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, ...), axs is a 2D array. You need to write axs[0,0] etc.. Alternatively, you can convert it to a 1D array;  axs = axs.flat.  Further, in Python, it is highly recommended to avoid for i in range(0, 4): to create a loop. Instead, for ax, variable in zip(axs.flat, variables): gives much cleaner code. It is less error-prone and easier to adapt to changes.
